# Linear time number calculation of 1's

Tags: algorithm

> Each row of an n x n array A consists of 1s and 0s such that, in any row i of A, all the 1s come before any 0s in that row. The number of 1s in row i is >= the number of 1's in row i+1, for i=0,1,···,n−2. A is already in memory, describe a method running in O(n) time for counting the number of 1s in the array A.

I am stuck for getting the time complexity. Any idea how I can proceed?

Comment: I'd suggest starting by drawing some examples and solving them by hand, using whatever shortcuts spring to mind.

Answer (score 0):

What we know: (1) the number of `1`s is not-increasing from row to row, and (2) all the `1`s in each row come "before" (let's say left of) the zeros.

Now imagine you started at the top row and counted `1`s all the way until reaching the first zero (on the first row). Call that index, where the `1`s meet the zeros, `i`.

As you move down to each successive row, which way would you never go to find the `i` for that row? (Hint: you'll never go to the right.)

Now think in total, how many cells can `i` move at most if in each row you start from the same index then move left to find the `i` (where the zeros and `1`s meet) for *that* row. And how many rows have you visited in total? Add those two up and you'll have the complexity.

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be solved in **`O(R+C)`**, where **`R`** represents number of rows and **`C`** represent number of columns.

The idea is simple *since*,

> The number of 1s in row **`i`** is >= the number of 1's in row **`i+1`**

which also means,

> The number of 0s in row **`i`** is <= the number of 0's in row **`i+1`**

So count the number of **0's** in **1<sup>st</sup>** row, which can be done in **`O(R)`** time. To count the number of **0's** in **2<sup>nd</sup>** row you don't need to start the count from beginning, since this row have more(or equal) **0's** than previous row.

Refer example for better explanation.

```
Example:

 1  1  1  0
 1  0  0  0
 0  0  0  0

First Row:  // Count number of 0's from backwards, only 1 zero in this case, so number of 1's = Column count(C) - number of 0's i.e. 3
 1  1  1  0

Second Row: // Iterate from current index towards left until 1st 1, so now no. of 0's is 3 so no. if 1's = C - no. of 0's = 1
 1  1  1  0
          |
 1  0  0  0
   <- <- <-

Third Row:
 1  1  1  0
          |
 1  0  0  0
   <- <- <-
    |
 0  0  0  0
<- <-
no. of 1's = C - no. of 0's = 0
```

Just add all no. of 1's. So answer is `3 + 1 + 0 =` **`4`**

[**Live Code**](https://ideone.com/Bz620u)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int arr[6][4] = {
    1,1,1,1,1,0,
    1,1,1,1,0,0,
    1,1,0,0,0,0,
    1,0,0,0,0,0
};

int countOnes(){
    int ans = 0, r = 6, c = 4, i = 0, j = c - 1;
    for(i = 0; i < r; i++){
        while(j>=0 && arr[i][j]==0)
            j--;
        ans+=(j+1);
    }
    return ans;
}

int main() {
    int onesCount = countOnes();
    cout<<onesCount;
    return 0;
}
```